# About names of variable scope in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

Recently I have been trying to learn to use TensorFlow, and I do not understand how variable scopes work exactly. In particular, I have the following problem:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.models.rnn import rnn_cell
from tensorflow.models.rnn import rnn

inputs = [tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[10,10]) for _ in range(5)]
cell = rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(10)
outpts, states = rnn.rnn(cell, inputs, dtype=tf.float32)

print outpts[2].name
# ==> u'RNN/BasicLSTMCell_2/mul_2:0'
```

Where does the  `'_2'` in `'BasicLSTMCell_2'` come from? How does it work when later using `tf.get_variable(reuse=True)` to get the same variable again?

edit: I think I find a related problem:

```py
def creating(s):
    with tf.variable_scope('test'):
        with tf.variable_scope('inner'):
            a=tf.get_variable(s,[1])
    return a

def creating_mod(s):
    with tf.variable_scope('test'):
        with tf.variable_scope('inner'):
            a=tf.Variable(0.0, name=s)
    return a

tf.ops.reset_default_graph()
a=creating('a')
b=creating_mod('b')
c=creating('c')
d=creating_mod('d')

print a.name, '\n', b.name,'\n', c.name,'\n', d.name
```

The output is

```py
test/inner/a:0 
test_1/inner/b:0 
test/inner/c:0 
test_3/inner/d:0
```

I'm confused...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `"_2"` in `"BasicLSTMCell_2"` relates to the [*name scope*](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/framework.html#Graph.name_scope) in which the op `outpts[2]` was created. Every time you create a new name scope (with [`tf.name_scope()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/framework.html#name_scope)) or variable scope (with [`tf.variable_scope()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#variable_scope)) a unique suffix is added to the current name scope, based on the given string, possibly with an additional suffix to make it unique.  The call to `rnn.rnn(...)` has the following pseudocode (simplified and using public API methods for clarity):

```py
outputs = []
with tf.variable_scope("RNN"):
  for timestep, input_t in enumerate(inputs):
    if timestep > 0:
      tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
    with tf.variable_scope("BasicLSTMCell"):
      outputs.append(...)
return outputs
```

If you look at the names of the tensors in `outpts`, you'll see that they are the following:

```py
>>> print [o.name for o in outpts]
[u'RNN/BasicLSTMCell/mul_2:0',
 u'RNN/BasicLSTMCell_1/mul_2:0',
 u'RNN/BasicLSTMCell_2/mul_2:0',
 u'RNN/BasicLSTMCell_3/mul_2:0',
 u'RNN/BasicLSTMCell_4/mul_2:0']
```

When you enter a new name scope (by entering a [`with tf.name_scope("..."):`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/framework.html#name_scope) or [`with tf.variable_scope("..."):`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#variable_scope) block), TensorFlow creates a new, *unique* name for the scope. The first time the `"BasicLSTMCell"` scope is entered, TensorFlow uses that name verbatim, because it hasn't been used before (in the `"RNN/"` scope). The next time, TensorFlow appends `"_1"` to the scope to make it unique, and so on up to `"RNN/BasicLSTMCell_4"`.

The main difference between variable scopes and name scopes is that a variable scope also has a set of name-to-[`tf.Variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Variable) bindings. By calling `tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()`, we instruct TensorFlow to *reuse* rather than create variables for the `"RNN/"` scope (and its children), after timestep 0. This ensures that the weights are correctly shared between the multiple RNN cells.

Comment: Could you point out the exact line of code where tf.name_scope is used? All I can find is `with tf.variable_scope(scope or type(self).__name__):  # "BasicLSTMCell" ` in rnn_cell.py

Comment: There are two places: the top-level (`"RNN"`) scope ([link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/97522f0acd53652baa57e42d06557ebb94bf0c4d/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py#L86)), and the nested (`"BasicLSTMCell"`) scope ([link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/97522f0acd53652baa57e42d06557ebb94bf0c4d/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell.py#L187)). Note that a call to `variable_scope()` implies a call to `name_scope()` (see implementation [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/97522f0acd53652baa57e42d06557ebb94bf0c4d/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py#L381)).

Comment: I edited the answer to make it clearer where `variable_scope()` is being used.

Comment: Thx, I more or less understand what happened. But I think it's also related to how you create the variables. It seems `tf.get_variables` and `tf.Variable` have different ways of generate variable names. While `tf.get_variables` creates new name_scope, it still name the variable with the variable_scope name, somehow...

Comment: Shouldn't `tf.variable_scope("BasicLSTMCell", reuse=True)` be `reuse=None` so that it inherits the outer scope reuse and is able to create variables in its first run?

Comment: Yes (although it doesn't seem to have any effect on the control flow).

Comment: May I ask why are both name_scope and variable_scope needed? I'm trying to set up TensorBoard. I noticed that most of the tutorials I found used name_scope, may I assume TensorBoard visualization would figure out things the same way if variable_scope is used instead? Thanks!

Comment: May I reopen the discussion (since I'm trying to figure out kind of the same question for myself). @mrry , if I got your explanation correctly, it seems to contradict the edit by the topic-starter, where creating `c` variable happens inside of the initial `test` scope, but not inside of `test_2`, as your explanation would imply: you state that re-entering a scope *always* creates a suffixed unique name... Could you clarify?

Answer (score 9):

The answer above is somehow misguiding.

Let me answer why you got two different scope names, even though it looks like that you defined two identical functions: `creating` and `creating_mod`.

This is simply because you used `tf.Variable(0.0, name=s)` to create the variable in the function `creating_mod`.

**ALWAYS use `tf.get_variable`**, if you want your variable to be recognized by scope!

Check out this [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1325) for more details.

Thanks!

Comment: I also ran into this problem. But, even always using tf.get_variable, I also get the "_1" addition in my variable scope

Comment: @mhz I got the "_1" addition too. In my case, it comes from train and test model