# Variable scopes get a number appended

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

There are some cases where I get a number appended to the variable scope (even if I set `reuse=True`)

Let's say I do something like:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Session() as session:
    graph = tf.Graph()
    with graph.as_default():
        with tf.variable_scope("Foo", reuse=True):
            tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float64, name="A")

        # Do something else here.. 

        with tf.variable_scope("Foo", reuse=True):
            tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float64, name="B")

        writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('/tmp/tf', graph=graph)
        writer.flush()
```

Why do I see (tensorboard) two groupings (Foo, Foo_1):

[image]

I would like A and B to be placed in the same grouping but still keep the two `with` statements separate.

I think a key difference with other existing questions is that I am asking: **How do I do this?**

Comment: show also you you create some variable and which one gets the `1` added

Comment: not sure what you mean

Comment: The `tf.get_variable` or `tf.Variable` call you're using inside the 2 `tf.variable_scope`

Comment: ok, I updated the example.. Now you can even run the code if you want.

Comment: This seems like a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34592172/1233251

Comment: @E_net4, this **is** a duplicate

Comment: that question is messy.. Would you mind adding an answer here?

Comment: @purpletentacle Unfortunately, that is not the recommended procedure. We can leave a tl;dr comment here, but it's best to incrementally improve what we consider a canonical question on the matter.

Comment: It is not about not reading. I think I have provided a good and clean minimal working example. In addition, The references do not give an answer on how to solve the problem.